# I try to copy and paste result range

Tags: copy, paste

' INPUT BOX

Dim x As Integer

Dim inp As String

Dim curcount As Integer

Dim performer As String

Dim projn As String

Dim cons As String

projnumber = Application.InputBox("enter project number", , 9999, , 1)

customer = Application.InputBox("customer name")

project_name = Application.InputBox("Project  name")

performer = Application.InputBox("performer name")

Model = Application.InputBox("model")

consulting = Application.InputBox("consulting engineer")

x = 2

Set countarea = Range("n2")

count ("n2")

curcount = Range("n2")

x = x + curcount

Set counter = Range("N" & x)

counter.Value = curcount

Set today = Range("D" & x)

today.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/y"

today.Value = Date

Range("A" & x) = projnumber

Range("B" & x) = customer

Range("c" & x) = project_name

Range("E" & x) = performer

Range("F" & x) = Model

Range("G" & x) = consulting

```
Sheets("DataSet").Range("A" & x & ":D" & x).copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A2").Paste
```